# RavenDB static index on dictionary

Tags: ravendb

I have an application that uses documents, that contain list of attributes in a dictionary, for some reason we need to use a static index and query/filter over these attributes.

A prototype looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore() { DefaultDatabase = "Test", Url = "http://localhost:8081" };
        store.Initialize();

        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Program).Assembly, store);

        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(new Document { Id = "1", Name = "doc_name", Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Type", "1" }, { "Status", "Active" } } });
            session.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            // works
            var l1 = session.Query<Document, Documents_Index>().Where(a => a.Attributes["Type"] == "1").ToList();
            // not working
            var l2 = session.Query<Document, Documents_Index>().Where(a => a.Attributes["Status"] == "Active").ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Documents_Index : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Document>
{
    public Documents_Index()
    {
        Map = docs => docs.Select(a =>
         new
         {
             a.Name,
             a.Attributes,
             Attributes_Type = a.Attributes["Type"]
         });
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

But since I need to query using any arbitrary Attribute name/value this index does solve our problem. Actually the list of attributes is known at run-time (so we tried modifying the Map expression to inject any number of attribute names, but so far we weren't successful). Is there a way how to define the index in some dynamic fashion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write it like:

```
public class Documents_Index : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Document>
{
    public Documents_Index()
    {
        Map = docs => docs.Select(a =>
         new
         {
             a.Name,
             _ = a.Attributes.Select(x=>CreateField("Attributes_"+x.Key, x.Value),
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like expected, but realized the '_' property name is important and not to be changed